# Selenium Python. Nothing happened after I clicked on radio-button (Chrome Webdriver)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[I practice with selenium on this site](https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form)

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("gender-radio-1")
element.click()
time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **execute_script** to click on Male radio button :

```
driver.get("https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form")
male_web_element = driver.find_element_by_id("gender-radio-1")
print(male_web_element.is_selected())
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", male_web_element)
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: It would help to include the `import` statements as well

Comment: @JD2775 : Thnx for pointing it out, Updated !

Comment: @Faust Pear  : You may want to use the updated code, since it did not work with WebDriverWait so I had to use `execute_script`